# Check if Adobe Acrobat Reader is open and get the filename of the pdf

Tags: c#, adobe-reader

I am searching a way to check with C#, if there is an open Adobe Acrobat Reader and when it is, get the filename with the path of the open PDF.

Can someone give me a tipp?

Thank you.

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something close to your requirement

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a298349a-a59a-4c6e-ad42-bd9f0cf80fb0/

Comment: In the Window-Title there is only the filename - but I need the whole path of the file.

Comment: You need to dig deeper,have you ever looked at process explorer.It shows an exe and the files it has access too..so search for that way.

Comment: I know the process explorer - But to get the Filehandles, I have to write a driver :-(

Answer (score 2):

you can get this working with Process class.

```
Process[] acrobats = Process.GetProcessesByName("Acrord32");
foreach (Process p in acrobats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowTitle);
}
```

Hope this gives a clue...

Comment: The problem is, in the Window-Title there is only the Filename - But I need the complete path.